# Mutliple root tag error Navigation Drawer Android Studio

Tags: java, android, navigation, navigation-drawer

I am new to Android, Java and coding in general. I am trying to make an Android app using Android Studio. I am creating a navigation drawer for the same. I am at the first stage in the process that is creating the Design Layout. IT is giving me multiple toot tag error. I would appreciate help on where I am going wrong and how to fix it. Thank you in advance!

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
android:divider="@android:color/transparent" android:dividerHeight="0dp"
android:background="#cccc" tools:context=".NavigationDrawerFragment" />
```

Correct code -

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- Side navigation drawer UI -->

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent" android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#cccc" tools:context=".NavigationDrawerFragment" />
```

Comment: Please post you complete layout xml file and make sure there is only one element on top of the tree.

Comment: I resolved the issue. It was a very silly mistake after the <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout " " > I had </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout> and then the attributes for ListView. I will keep those points in mind from next time. Thank you anyway!